# Viewing of CANbus data on Industrial Panel PC

Tags: c, arduino-uno, can-bus, stm32f4discovery

I have an Industrial PC which has Windows OS. I want to send some data over SPI-CAN module using Arduino to CAN connection of Panel PC.

You can see the system; [MCP2515 module usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXdC6.jpg)

Also you can see the application example like cangaroo on panel pc [can trace software cangaroo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I9iL.jpg)

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <mcp2515.h>

struct can_frame canMsg1;
struct can_frame canMsg2;
MCP2515 mcp2515(10);


void setup() {
  canMsg1.can_id  = 0x0F6;
  canMsg1.can_dlc = 8;
  canMsg1.data[0] = 0x8E;
  canMsg1.data[1] = 0x87;
  canMsg1.data[2] = 0x32;
  canMsg1.data[3] = 0xFA;
  canMsg1.data[4] = 0x26;
  canMsg1.data[5] = 0x8E;
  canMsg1.data[6] = 0xBE;
  canMsg1.data[7] = 0x86;

  canMsg2.can_id  = 0x036;
  canMsg2.can_dlc = 8;
  canMsg2.data[0] = 0x0E;
  canMsg2.data[1] = 0x00;
  canMsg2.data[2] = 0x00;
  canMsg2.data[3] = 0x08;
  canMsg2.data[4] = 0x01;
  canMsg2.data[5] = 0x00;
  canMsg2.data[6] = 0x00;
  canMsg2.data[7] = 0xA0;
  
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  mcp2515.reset();
  mcp2515.setBitrate(CAN_125KBPS);
  mcp2515.setNormalMode();
  
  Serial.println("Example: Write to CAN");
}

void loop() {
  mcp2515.sendMessage(&canMsg1);
  mcp2515.sendMessage(&canMsg2);

  Serial.println("Messages sent");
  
  delay(100);
}
```

My question is, how can I follow the data transmitted from Arduino to Panel PC? I have downloaded some software to Panel PC but not sure how to see the Can connection of the pc?

I mean when I open the can interfaces I suppose to see some kind of communication on the app.

Comment: Some simple debugging tips: (1) Use an oscilloscope / digital analyzer and check your SPI. Is everything hooked up correctly and are the expected signals (CLK, MISO, MOSI, CS) on the expected lines? If everything is correct check CAN H/L in the same way using an oscilloscope. (2) If the Windows device is known to work, maybe try reversing the approach and instead send something from the Windows device. If it works at least the interrupt line (INT) from the CAN module to the Arduino should show some action.

Comment: Are you using Arduino Uno or STM32F4? Only tag your question with relevant tags - for now it is unclear what you are doing. The general recommendation is to not use 1990s microcontrollers with 1990s external CAN controllers over SPI. But instead pick something modern with a built-in CAN controller.

Comment: If you can help about using any MCU (w STM / Arduino Uno) , I am using the both. You can check out the images to find out what I am trying to do. It should be really easy to understand after reading my question that  what I am trying to do :) Those are the materials that I have. Thanks for your advice...

Comment: Well, Arduino isn't suitable for industrial applications in the first place, so picking STM32 should be a "no brainer". Pick one with a modern CAN peripheral on-board, then you can forget all about skunky SPI interfaces to some external CAN controller from 1995 or whatever. ["Not Recommended for new designs"](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/mcp2515) means that the part is not recommended for new designs. Similarly, do not use Windows 95 in new products either.